# Trace Command on RL5

Tags: redhat

Anyone got a idea how to install the [trace](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdln_trace.htm) command on RHEL5 to monitor variable access? I already googled it and search via yum but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The command you link to is a built in TCL command. Do you have TCL installed?

```
yum install tcl
```

Edit: Try the following program:

```
  proc tellme {id a e op} {
    puts "  $id a=$a e=$e op=$op\
                ax=[info exists ::$a] ex=[info exists ::${a}($e)]"
  }

  proc do {args} {
    puts "<$args>"
    uplevel $args
  }

  trace var a wu {tellme array}
  trace var a(1) wu {tellme element}

  puts [trace vinfo a]
  puts [trace vinfo a(1)]

  do set a(0) zero
  do set a(1) one
  do set a(2) two
  do unset a(0)
  do unset a(2)
  do unset a

  # output is:
  #
  #   {wu {tellme array}}
  #   {wu {tellme element}}
  #   <set a(0) zero>
  #     array a=a e=0 op=w ax=1 ex=1
  #   <set a(1) one>
  #     array a=a e=1 op=w ax=1 ex=1
  #     element a=a e=1 op=w ax=1 ex=1
  #   <set a(2) two>
  #     array a=a e=2 op=w ax=1 ex=1
  #   <unset a(0)>
  #     array a=a e=0 op=u ax=1 ex=0
  #   <unset a(2)>
  #     array a=a e=2 op=u ax=1 ex=0
  #   <unset a>
  #     array a=a e= op=u ax=0 ex=0
  #     element a=a e=1 op=u ax=0 ex=0
```

(From http://wiki.tcl.tk/1505 )

Comment: yes, installed it, but it didn't include the trace command for an unknown reason.

Answer (score 1):

You may be getting your UNIXes mixed up ... on Linux the command [`strace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) performs a system trace - that may be what you're looking for. Try a `yum install strace`

Alternatively you may be looking for [`traceroute`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) to perform a network trace. Install that with a `yum install traceroute`